# How can i show notification per user with jquery and php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want show notification per user via **API**
for example if call `api.php?user=1` via server or any admins, show alert to user1 if has any page, for example run `alert('hi user 1');` 
or call `api.php?user=2` via server or any admins, show alert to user2, for example run `alert('hi user 2');`

my solution is :

```
setInterval(function(){
  $.get('ajax_responder.php',dataObj,function(){
  });
},5000);
```

and in `api.php` saved request and in `ajax_responder.php` selected notification per user
but this solution not good,and reloaded per 5 second, i want better solution, when called `api.php` send request to user X
any have solution?!

Comment: A better solution would be using NodeJS, period.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way the user can receive your notification if the user is not querying the server repeatedly. You can use a [websocket](https://pusher.com/websockets) to send/receive bi-directional

Comment: Technically there is a way for the server to directly push notifications to the user called [Push Notifications](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/engage-and-retain/push-notifications/) with the new [Push API in HTML5](https://w3c.github.io/push-api/).

Answer (score 0):

You can do that.

Step 1) When admin user type message store it in database. you can refer below as example.

`TABLE NAME = USER_NOTIFICATION`

```
==================================
USER_ID  | IS_READ  | MESSAGE
==================================
1          0          Hello User 1
-----------------------------------
2          0          Hello User 2
-----------------------------------
```

Step 2) Now from front side write Ajax call to keep checking on every minute or 5 minutes interval (Interval depends on server capability to handle the requests), whether for particular login user is having any unread message.

If you are using MySQL then you can use this below query to check unread notifications

```
SELECT `message` from USER_NOTIFICATION WHERE `user_id` = 1 and `is_read` = 0
```

now after getting result from above query show it in notification div (Remember create notification div with fixed position so it always popup)

Step 3) when user read admin message that time set `is_read` flag to 1, so next time that same message will not appear to user

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: thanks, but my solution is it, i want other and better solution

Comment: What type of other solution, are you looking for specific flow or language or database or something, please clarify by mean "other and better solution" (Just trying to understand your requirements ;))